# Cannot POST form to local mysql server from locally hosted web page

Tags: php, node.js

I'm attempting to post the contents of a form to a locally hosted MySQL server and am receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed error when running the following php script.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbname = "test";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO data (nickname, location, crop, rowspacing, plantspacing, orientation)
VALUES ('$_POST[nickname-input]', '$_POST[location-input]', '$_POST[crop-input]', '$_POST[row-input]', '$_POST[plant-input], '$_POST[orientation-input]')");

?>
```

I have the SQL server host enabled with all priveleges as seen here.
[image]

The php script is running in the following html code where it obtains the proper values

```
<form name="main" action="insert.php" method="POST">
      <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="medium-2 cell">
        <label for="nickname" class="middle">Nickname</label>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-10 cell">
        <input type="text" id="nickname-input" required placeholder="Give your field a nickname for easier reference">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="small-2 cell">
        <label for="location" class="middle">Location</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-10 cell">
        <input type="text" id="location-input" required placeholder="Tell us where you are so we can obtain location based information">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-x">
      <div class="small-2 cell">
        <label for="crop-type" class="middle">Crop Type</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-10 cell">
        <select id="crop-input">
            <option value="" hidden disabled selected required>Supported Crops Shown here</option>
            <option value="pistachio">Pistachios</option>
            <option value="almond">Almonds</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="small-2 cell">
        <label for="row-spacing" class="middle">Row Spacing (ft)</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-10 cell">
        <input type="number" id="row-input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 cell">
        <label for="plant-spacing" class="middle">Plant Spacing (ft)</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-10 cell">
        <input type="number" id="plant-input" required>
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 cell">
      <label for="row-orientation" class="middle">Row Orientation</label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-10 cell">
        <select id="orientation-input" required>
            <option value="north-south">North-South</option>
            <option value="east-west">East-West</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      </div>




    <div class="medium-12 large-12 cell">
        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit" style="padding: 0px 35px"> Save </button>
        </div>
        <div class="button">Add Another Field</div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

So to reiterate, I'm receving a 405 Method Not Allowed error when trying to post the above form data to the MySQL database. Both the website and database are hosted locally on my machine.

EDIT: I just looked in the node.js logs for my site and found this:

```
"POST /insert.php" Error (404): "Not found"
```

The source of the 405 error was from chrome developer tools.

Comment: Sounds like you may have dissallowed POST in the apache config

Comment: I haven't changed any values in the apache config files. I looked through the php.ini file and didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: can you send a POST request manually via `curl` or similar successfully?

Comment: I'm running the MySQL server on XAMPP. I can use the XAMPP command line to successfully manipulate the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using `npm http-server` since you referenced "node.js logs", which does **not** support `POST` due to it being a read-only server. You can try alternatives like [server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/server) or [JSON-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) which do support `POST`, but still, node won't support PHP by default, it only supports javascript.

If you are already using XAMPP for the MySQL, you can just host the entire thing there and do away with the node server entirely, or rewrite your php code in javascript via [node.js mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

If I emulate what I think is your setup, I get the same error when submitting the form:

```
D:\Test>http-server --cors -p 80

Starting up http-server, serving ./

Available on:  
  http://192.168.0.10:80  
  http://127.0.0.1:80  
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server  
[Thu May 24 2018 15:42:35 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] "GET /test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
[Thu May 24 2018 15:42:41 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] "POST /insert.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
[Thu May 24 2018 15:42:41 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)] "POST /insert.php" Error (404): "Not found"
```